# Does the ending choice depend on the player character?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I've finished *Divinity: Original Sin II* playing as Fane. I've initially agreed with Lucien to his plan regarding sealing the Veil and removing the Source from the world (only to make the final fight easier - otherwise you have to fight both Lucien and Braccus). However, after killing the final boss, you can decide the destiny of Veil - and for me [some of the choices](https://divinityoriginalsin2.wiki.fextralife.com/Endings) were locked off (some for obvious reasons - you can't rule with the Doctor if you've killed him), basically leaving me only with agreeing to Lucian's plan or releasing the Eternals and imprisoning all mortals.

If you play as another, pre-made character, is your choice also limited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In DE(Definitive Edition), doesn't matter if you choose to fight Lucian or surrender your source to start the fight, after winning, you will have a 2-stage choice:

- 1 Choose divinity

  - 1.1 Become divine
  - 1.2 Give source to everyone
  - 1.3 Purge all source to seal the veil(that is same as agree to sacrifice source, but this is the final decision.)
  - extra choices if your main is undead or Fane
- 2 Reject divinity

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question - playing as Fane I couldn't choose your answers 1.1 and 1.2. The only options I had was to either bring the Eternals back or agree to Lucian's plan. Hence I'm asking is there a limit if you play as another character

Comment: @Yasskier If I choose to fight Lucian, 1.1 and 1.2 are available to me, including playing as Fane or undead or other origin or custom character. Will have to check if that change if I go the surrender route.

Comment: @Yasskier Are you playing DE? I dig out my Fane profile and did the final fight again, but choose to surrender before fight start. After defeating Braccus, I have the same 2 stage options, no limitation. I updated my answer.

Comment: No, it was not DE version. Maybe it has changed in the latest version then

Comment: @Yasskier DE should be a free update, and lot of bug fix, exp changes and added features(like armor set). But some logical bug(sotry-wise) still there.